# Textmate to browse C++ project with a bunch of files and CUDA

Tags: c++, cuda, textmate, code-analysis

I am new to Textmate. I have to work on a CUDA C++ project and at the moment just would like to get the project (bunch of files and directories), start with the main C++ file and from there, selecting functions and that Textmate jumps to the definitions which usually are in other files. Is it possible with Textmate and moreover with CUDA?

Do not need to compile, just efficiently browse code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the [CTags bundle](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/CTags.tmbundle/) for TextMate. [Here's a tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20170701205747/http://gerd.knops.org/?p=7) that explains how to do by hand what the bundle does for you.

Comment: @gpu_drug: I guess it'll work since CUDA functions are C/C++ functions, ctags (the engine used by the bundle) will recognize them.

Comment: Tutorial link is broken.

Comment: @Roberto Found it on wayback machine, fixed the link