# Syntax Highlighting for Textmate and CUDA

Tags: macos, cuda, textmate

Does anybody know how I can add syntax highlighting for CUDA (.cu) files in Textmate for mac. I would be enough if he would recognize a .cu file as a .c file with the same highlighting. The Problem is if I save it as a .cu I don't have any highlighting.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Textmate to browse C++ project with a bunch of files and CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094502/textmate-to-browse-c-project-with-a-bunch-of-files-and-cuda)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download this [package](https://github.com/harrism/sublimetext-cuda-cpp/archive/master.zip) designed by "sublimetext-cuda-cpp".

You install the package by cloning the [repository](https://github.com/harrism/sublimetext-cuda-cpp) to your Sublime Text 2 Packages directory:

```
cd <package directory>
git clone git://github.com/harrism/sublimetext-cuda-cpp.git
```

Restart Sublime Text afterward, switch to CUDA C++ as highlighting profile and try it out with one of the commands above.

You don't have git installed in your mac, you have to download it and install it, [here](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git) you have all the files and information need to install gif.

You can try also to use [CTags bundle](http://svn.textmate.org/trunk/Bundles/CTags.tmbundle/) for TextMate. All the details about how to install it [here](http://gerd.knops.org/?p=7).

Or you can do also download this [bundle](http://gerd.knops.org/files/CTags.tmbundle.zip) which (in cutting-edge versions of TextMate) can be installed by unpacking the zip file and double-clicking on the CTags.tmbundle file. Help is available within the bundle.